# Python loop generating Excelfiles

Tags: python, pandas, loops

i have following code:

```py
#import requests
from pandas import pandas as pd
base_url = "https://baden.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/groupPage?championship=B2+S+2022&group="
Gruppe = ["1","24"] 
Team = ["H1","H2"] 

#Tabelle & Spielplan
for element in Gruppe:
    df = pd.read_html(base_url+str(element), index_col=0)
    for name in Team:
        df[0].to_csv('Exporte/Gruppe_'+str(element)+'_'+str(name)+'_Tabelle.csv', index = False)
        df[1].to_csv('Exporte/Gruppe_'+str(element)+'_'+str(name)+'_Spielplan.csv', index = False)
```

I only need the excel files generated for **Gruppe "1"/ Team "H1"** as well as **Gruppe "2"/ Team "H2"** but not for **Gruppe "1"/ Team "H2"** and not for **Gruppe "2"/ Team "H1**"

Anyone able to tell me how to setup the loop to get only the desired Excelfiles?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: @SalazarSlytherin if your columns are limited to 2-3, why do it in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip()`:

```
#import requests
from pandas import pandas as pd
base_url = "https://baden.liga.nu/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTENDE.woa/wa/groupPage?championship=B2+S+2022&group="
Gruppe = ["1","24"] 
Team = ["H1","H2"] 

#Tabelle & Spielplan
for element,name in zip(Gruppe, Team):
    df = pd.read_html(base_url+str(element), index_col=0)
    df[0].to_csv('Exporte/Gruppe_'+str(element)+'_'+str(name)+'_Tabelle.csv', index = False)
    df[1].to_csv('Exporte/Gruppe_'+str(element)+'_'+str(name)+'_Spielplan.csv', index = False)
```

From the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip): `zip` iterates over several iterables in parallel, producing tuples with an item from each one.

An example from the doc:

```
for item in zip([1, 2, 3], ['sugar', 'spice', 'everything nice']):
    print(item)

>>> (1, 'sugar')
>>> (2, 'spice')
>>> (3, 'everything nice')
```